# What's the fastest way to find and replace in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, tagging

I need a way of replacing some variables within a passed string.

Example:

I pass through "#fname# jumped over the tall wall to get his phone with the number #phone#".

I need the string to be replaced with "John jumped over the tall wall to get his phone with the number 0123456789".

I have used str_replace in the past but they is alot of tags (#example#) to be replaced per execution - 1000+, and i am wary of speed performance..

Maybe a regex with preg_replace? The language is PHP.

Thank you.

Kyle

Comment: The only helpful answer to this is: "compare in a benchmark"

Comment: Regular expressions are not a magic wand that solves all problems.  Specifically in this case, they add no value to you.  They don't make your problem clearer, and they will make things slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use arrays with [`str_replace`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

So, let's say you had these tags to replace:

```
$search = array(
    '#firstname#',
    '#lastname#',
    '#phone#',
    '#foobar',
);
```

And you wanted to use this data:

```
$replace = array(
    'John',
    'Doe',
    '5555553535',
    'baz',
);
```

And you had a list of strings you wanted to do it in:

```
$strings = array(
    'My First Name is: #firstname#',
    'My Last Name is: #lastname#',
    'My Contact Info Is: #phone#, #foobar#',
);
```

You could call:

```
$populatedStrings = str_replace($search, $replace, $strings);
```

Which would result in:

```
array(
    'My First Name is: John',
    'My Last Name is: Doe',
    'My Contact Info Is: 5555555353, baz',
);
```

So you can do a lot in one shot, and it should be much faster than doing anything with a regex for this kind of operation (REGEX could be better if you wanted multiple replaces for each tag, eg: `array('#firstname#', '#fname#', '#givenname#', '#gname#')` all for first name...)

Answer (score 2):

Note that Regular Expressions are slower than inbuild PHP functions when manipulating strings. RegExps should be used for complex identifiers/isolators/manipulations, rule of thumb is if a PHP string function can be used, it should be (it's faster!)

Comment: Not necessarily in this case. Running 1000 `str_replace()` s may be slower than one `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: @Pekka: It *may* be slower, but with the overhead of 1000 function calls with the `$callback` may cancel any gain by the regex (the only way to tell would be a benchmark, but I'd be very surprised if the difference is significant)...

Comment: @Pekka you can add an array to `str_replace`. Not sure how that goes about the replacement internally, but my assumption is anything that uses a callback is slower because you have to invoke the callback.

Comment: the array option changes things. I'm doing a small edit to your answer so I can remove my downvote

Answer (score 1):

str_replace would still be faster than preg_replace. Sorry, but str_replace is your best option.

Comment: So something like: http://paste-it.net/public/m0fd300/?

+1 Gordon, benchmarking is required.

Answer (score 0):

[`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback), might work for this because it would walk through the string only once. You would have to store the tags you want to replace inside the callback function, e.g. in an array.

I can't say whether this is massively faster / more resource-efficient than `str_replace()` - you'd have to do some benchmarks.